# Handling null values in spark using only java rdd

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have read a csv file using java RDD, split it and remove header from it but when reading the records it is giving:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

as file has two empty lines at the end.

I want to know how to handle these null values but I have to perform everything using only Java RDD.

Comment: Can you add some code, so we can help better ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the empty string lines while you are looping over records, so your code will be like this:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CSV Reader").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> inputfile = sc.textFile("path/input.csv");

    inputfile.foreach(string -> {
        if (string != null && !string.trim().isEmpty()) {
            // Reading the record ...
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am using the below code but it is giving 0 results:

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CSV Reader").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> inputfile = sc.textFile("path/input.csv");

Comment: @PayalBansal, I have updated the answer, it is just you have to check empty string.